# In what context would native English speakers say "happen with" as opposed to "happen to"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Let's say I have given up my job and started drinking out of a sudden? Would be natural to say *happen with*? For example:

> You quit your job, started drinking. Whatever happended **with** you?

In what context native English speakers would never say *happen to*?

Answer (score 1):

If you have been dismissed from your job, that is something that has happened *to* you (by the actions of somebody else).

If you quit your job for no apparent reason and begin to behave out of character, it could also be said that something has happened *with* you (changes in your mental state).

Comment: In BrE we usually say, 'what(ever) happened to you', not 'what(ever) happened with you'. 'Happen with' appears mostly in sentences like, "It won't happen with him as president."

Comment: *If you have been dismissed from your job, that is something that has happened to you (**by the actions of somebody else**).* - but something could also happen **with you** by the actions of somebody else. For instance, **You acted ugly, what happened with you? I'm just tired, you've been too hard on me lately**.

Comment: @Anatolii Well, I would class that as 'a change in mental state'! I didn't mean to imply that such changes don't have a cause.

Comment: Let's say I have been scared and that is written all over my face. Would someone ask "what happened to you" or "what happened with your"?

Comment: Probably "What (has) happened to you?", assuming you have been scared by someone else or some incident you have witnessed.

Comment: @KateBunting So, can we classify them as follows - "`happen to you` - external events or actions affect you (often negatively but positively too), `happen with you` - you've changed internally as a person" ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by my answer (although you could use _happen to_ for both).